# Vimscript with Python 3

Tags: python, vim

I am trying to use python module written in python 3 in Vimscript .vim plugin. Though it does not work correctly.

After hours of research, googling etc. I think that the problem is that Vimscript (maybe only on my PC ?) uses old Python interpreter, since print(sys.path) shows:

```
'/usr/lib/python2.6', '/usr/lib/python2.6/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-tk','/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/gtk-2.0'
```

When I try to run the module in Eclipse with PyDev and interpreter set to 3.0 version, module works and sys.path shows:

```
'/usr/lib/python3.1', '/usr/lib/python3.1/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python3.1/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/#python3.1/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'.
```

How can I tell vimscript to use python 3 interpreter ? I am using debian OS system.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you have python3 included? (:version)
Do you call :py or :py3?

Comment: I had both py and py3 included. I figured out that the problem was that you can not run both at the same time. Since some plugins loaded before used py, calling py3 caused an error that this feature is disabled.